# Worst-case time complexity of Python's int.bit_length()

Tags: python, time-complexity

When we call the function [int.bit_length](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) passing an integer `n`,
is the worst-case time complexity `O(log(n))` or Python uses some trick to improve it (e.g. storing the position of the most significant bit of `n` when it is created)?

Answer (score 3):

[In CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e4c431ecf50def40eb93c3969c1e4eeaf7bf32f1/Objects/longobject.c#L5389-L5440), for values with fewer internal-representation digits than `PY_SSIZE_T_MAX/PyLong_SHIFT` – i.e. fewer than `PY_SSIZE_T_MAX` binary digits – it’s calculated from the number of internal digits, yes:

```c
msd = ((PyLongObject *)self)->ob_digit[ndigits-1];
msd_bits = bits_in_digit(msd);

if (ndigits <= PY_SSIZE_T_MAX/PyLong_SHIFT)
    return PyLong_FromSsize_t((ndigits-1)*PyLong_SHIFT + msd_bits);
```

Otherwise, it goes through bigints again, for overall time complexity of O(log log N) (which isn’t exactly true either in this strange mix of practice and theory, so…).

```c
/* expression above may overflow; use Python integers instead */
result = (PyLongObject *)PyLong_FromSsize_t(ndigits - 1);
if (result == NULL)
    return NULL;
x = (PyLongObject *)PyLong_FromLong(PyLong_SHIFT);
if (x == NULL)
    goto error;
y = (PyLongObject *)long_mul(result, x);
Py_DECREF(x);
if (y == NULL)
    goto error;
Py_DECREF(result);
result = y;

x = (PyLongObject *)PyLong_FromLong((long)msd_bits);
if (x == NULL)
    goto error;
y = (PyLongObject *)long_add(result, x);
Py_DECREF(x);
if (y == NULL)
    goto error;
Py_DECREF(result);
result = y;

return (PyObject *)result;
```

tl;dr: it’s O(1)

Comment: It is really strange... How can it run in log(log n)? If we do a loop through all the words, then it should run in log_B(n) where B is the bit-length of each word (for instance, B = 64). This code is obfuscated for me :/

Comment: @HilderVítorLimaPereira There is never a loop through all the words. It’s the number of words in the integer representing the number of bits that becomes significant for values large enough, where “large enough” is “too large to exist” for real-world values of `SSIZE_MAX`.