# How to find pair of numbers whose xor ==n

Tags: python, algorithm, bitwise-operators

I am new to bit operations i have this problem and i cant figure out how to slove it
**Problem**
Find pairs whose xor is is equals to a value say n and return the minumum diffrence pair

```
example n=5 possible pairs are 1-4,9-12 and so on
result is 4-1 as the diffrence of 4-1 is minimum
```

brute force is not applicable here as the range is very large upto 1<n<10^18
any hint?

Comment: there will be lot of combinations

Comment: HINT: Write the number and the answer in base 2.  There is a very simple pattern that is obvious once you spot it.

Comment: Why isn't the result 9-12? It has the same difference as 1-4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `n` is positive. First reduce `n` to `m` which is the highest power of 2 less than `n` using a O(log n) loop:

```
m = n
while m & (m-1):
    m = m & (m-1)
```

Then your answer will be `m` and `n-m`.

Let me try to give a sketch of proof:

It should be trivial to see why this holds for `m ^ (n-m) == n`. Now I prove why this pair has the minimal difference. Let `m ^ x == n` for some `m` and `x` and without loss of generality, assume `m > x`. We do not assume `m == x` because otherwise the `n==0`. While maintaining `m ^ x == n`, if we flip the same zero bit to one on both of them, we increase them by the same amount and thus their difference `m-x` will still be the same. Hence we can also assume bits on `m` and `x` will never be both 1 on the same position. If we flip the bit which was 0 on `m` but 1 on `x`, it will decrease on `x` but increase on `m` and the difference `m-x` will be greater. If we flip the bit which was 1 on `m` but 0 on `x`, the difference *might* be less. Therefore, the pair with minimal difference is such that we cannot do the last flip, i.e. such `m` that flipping any 1-bit on `m` will make `m < x`.

Comment: Ah, the downvotes are a shame. I think this is the proper solution, but I guess people want you to explain it.

Comment: While this answer is correct in theory, in 64-bit Python 3 a faster solution that costs *O(1)* in time complexity would be `m` and `n-m` after `m = 1 << n.bit_length() - 1` instead, since the `int.bit_length` method costs [*O(1)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461990/worst-case-time-complexity-of-pythons-int-bit-length) when the given integer is no greater than `2**63-1`, which is the case for this question since `10**18` is less than `2**63-1`.